# Xtext in Eclipse - modifying DSL without closing 2nd instance of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, dsl, xtext

While creating some DSL using Xtext, every time I want to test my custom language I create artifacts and run new instance of Eclipse, to write script in that language. Is it possible, to simply make changes to Xtext code and apply them to that instance without closing it (in other words: making changes "in real time") ?

Comment: I am checking my grammar by writing test cases, but this not applicable for colors and ui changes etc.  AFAIK no instance run for xtext.

Comment: Good idea to proceed test cases. My next idea is to make some kind of script to auto it.

Comment: What about „unit tests“ ?

Comment: and depending on your change you can use debugging / hot code replacement